# when using pyinstaller when connecting to the webcam all is well, when connecting to the IP camera an error occurs

Tags: opencv, pyinstaller

when using pyinstaller when connecting to the webcam all is well, when connecting to the IP camera an error occurs :
error text: File "15.py", line 8, in 
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

```py
import cv2
stream = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.161.70/1')


while True:

    r, f = stream.read()
    cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)
    #r,f = imutils.resize(f, width=400)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to debug like this, but it didn't work

```py
import imutils
import cv2######################ip camers
stream = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.161.70:554/Streaming/Channels/201')



while True:

    r, f = stream.read()
    if r==False:
        cv2.waitKey(1000)
        print('false')
        stream.open ('rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.161.70:554/Streaming/Channels/201')
    else:
        cv2.imshow('IP Camera stream',f)
        f = imutils.resize(f, width=400)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
input()
```

Comment: I recommend you to always check the return value of VideoCapture.read (r  in your case) to avoid errors like this and to be able to debug faster. The problem is that it cannot connect to the camera, are you sure the ip is the correct one? are you sure the port is the correct one (no port is 80 by default, normally rtsp is on the 554)? are you sure there is no firewall preventing the connection?

Comment: yes camera is work I checked in VLC media player. In example on this site i pointed the wrong row. Sorry correct this 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.161.70:554/Streaming/Channels/201'.when I run the file *.py all work. But ufter i convert file in *.exe with pyinstaller all not work. About debugging I added code which tried to use for debug.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem. Before convert pyinstaller  don't add file opencv_ffmpeg410_64.dll in folder with *.exe file. For correct work need copy this file from opencv folder inside folder with *.exe file